# Possible to clean img/p folder in prestashop?

Tags: image, ftp, prestashop

How is it with the img/p folder in Prestashop 1.6.0.9? Is it possible fully to clean it? Cause this folder went to big now, and FTP is almost full now, i need space. For example when i renamed it on FTP, all images on the website worked, and prestashop created automaticaly one new img/p folder, and all seems that works right (also when the initial img/p was out after renaming). Thanks in advance.

Comment: the `p` stands for products so that's your products image folder.
You can clean it by removing products and/or removing Images under `Preferences` > `Images` but that's not recommended as your theme might use those

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer. And what will happen if I will use in **Preferences > Images** option to regenerate product images ? will it help? or will it substitute old images?

Comment: Regenrating images will delete all images and then regenerate only existing product images, maybe this will make you gain some disk space

Answer (score 0):

when you delete the folder you may see the images working, its from smarty cache, once you clear the smarty cache, presta default (not found) image will be shown.

Comment: Hi, so it means that this folder is necessery, important and can not be cleaned?

Comment: Hi, btw i discovered that my **img/p** folder increased much after i tried to generate sitemap via gsitemap module. Is it possible that this was the reason?